# ¿Por qué el script de php me muestra siempre los valores incorrectos?

Tags: formularios, condiciones, if, php7, else

Tengo un script en `php7` que recibe datos de un formulario que genera aleatoriamente un país de una lista y abre un desplegable para seleccionar la capital correcta. Mi código es este:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>Paises y Capitales</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> <!-- Establecemos UTF-8 como codificación estándar para evitar problemas con las tildes> <!-->
    </head>
    <body>
    ¿Cuál es la capital de <?php
    $rutacapitales = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/practica2/p2/capitales.txt";
    $rutapaises = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/practica2/p2/paises.txt";
    if (is_file($rutapaises) && is_readable($rutapaises) && is_file($rutacapitales)&& is_readable($rutacapitales)) {
        //Mostramos el país aleatiorio
        $fichpaises = fopen("$rutapaises","r");
        $listapais = file("$rutapaises");
        $fichcapit = fopen("$rutacapitales","r");
        $listcapi = file("$rutacapitales");
        $pais= $listapais[mt_rand(0,count($listapais)-1)];
        echo $pais." ? <br>";
        // enviamos el pais por el formulario

        echo"<form method ='post' action='parte2.php'>";
        echo "<select name='capitales'>";
                     for ($i=0; $i <count($listcapi) ; $i++) { 
                         echo "<option value=$listcapi[$i]> $listcapi[$i] </option>";
                     }
         echo"</select>";
         echo '<input type="hidden" name="pais" value="'.$pais.'">';
         echo "<input type='submit' value='Comprobar capital'>";
         echo "</form>";
         fclose($fichcapit);
         fclose($fichpaises);
    }
    else {print_r($paiscapital);
        die("El archivo no existe, o no se puede leer");
    }
            ?>

</body>
</html>
```

El segundo script valida la resuesta, pero sin embargo, marque lo que marque siempre me lo da como incorrecto, y no sé por qué es.
Este es mi código:

```
<?php
        //Comprobamos la llegada de los datos del formulario
    if (isset($_POST['capitales']) && isset($_POST['pais'])) {
        $capitalresp = (string) $_POST['capitales'];
        $pais = (string)$_POST['pais'];
        echo "Has introducido $capitalresp";
        //Abrimos los ficheros otra vez y comprobamos
        $rutacapi = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/practica2/p2/capitales.txt";
        $rutapais = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/practica2/p2/paises.txt";

        //Volcamos el contenido de los dos archivos
        $listacapi =file("$rutacapi");
        $listapais = file("$rutapais");
        //mezlamos los arrays
        $paiscapital = array_combine($listapais,$listacapi);
        //Contamos los elementos
        if (count($listapais) == count($listacapi)) {
               if ($paiscapital["$pais"] == $capitalresp) {
                   echo "Es correcto";
                 }
                 else {
                     echo "No es correcto";
                 }
                    }
        else {
            die("No coiniden las capitales con los países");
        }
                }
    else {
        die("Debes seleccionar una opción ");
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: He comprobado que lo que recibo por el post es correcto

Comment: El debugger no muestra ningun problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al convertir en arrays el contenido de los ficheros con file() no utilizas el parámetro **FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES** , con lo que los caracteres de salto de línea se mantienen en los valores y en las claves del array que utilizas para comparar.

Al renderizar el HTML se eliminan estos saltos de línea, con lo que las comparaciones dan resultados negativos.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que estás pidiendo que extraiga un valor de un array usando un `string` en lugar de un `int`.

Cambia

```
if ($paiscapital["$pais"] == $capitalresp) {
    echo "Es correcto";
} else {
    echo "No es correcto"
}
```

por

```
if ($paiscapital[$pais] == $capitalresp) {
    echo "Es correcto";
} else {
    echo "No es correcto"
}
```

Comment: Pero $pais es un string sí o sí

Comment: No. no era ese el problema

Comment: Pues es uno de tantos. Los índices de un array, son siembre numéricos, no pueden ser `string`.